# Will Windows' "reset" feature behave properly for a PC with some programs installed on another drive?

Tags: windows-10

I am considering this reset feature. My current situation is that I have some programs that I use most often, like Chrome, installed on my C drive, while I install others on my D drive. My assumption is that if I choose a full reset and select to keep all files and programs, Windows won't consider what I've installed on my D drive and then there will be issues as a result (i.e., an incomplete Start Menu, etc.). Does anyone know?

Comment: Before making any major change, make **disk images of both drives**, That way, you can test Windows Refresh with impunity -- if anything goes wrong, restore to *exactly* as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 won't touch other drivers but it will delete all apps and settings have you made in your **Main driver C**.

also this is helpful from Microsoft help website:

> @"DYARIBARHAM":
>
> Files in your user profile folder (C:\Users\YourName) are saved as
> expected but files stored directly in the users folder (C:\Users) and
> not in a specific user profile are NOT saved. The Public user profile
> (C:\Users\Public) is NOT saved as well.

[source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/reset-this-pc-keep-my-files-option/94713a8d-b8f5-4fef-bf93-52032dd5ea49)

Answer (score 0):

The answer might differ per each installed product.

The "Keep all files and programs" means that the reset will not touch
program installations on disk and in the registry.

There is no documentation about which registry keys are re-initialized
by the reset, so it all depends on whether the product installation used
standard well-known registry keys, or on whether it encroached on
keys that Windows considers as its own.

So let's say as an answer that most products will stay functional,
with no difference wherever they were installed, but some other may
need repair or re-installation.

From my personal experience, there may be some rare cases that a product
will survive, but might still somewhat malfunction.
A repair or re-installation will fix the problem.

I suggest ensuring that you keep installation media for your
important products, or be sure that you can download it from internet.